# How to insert a row using my userform vba code?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have created a userform and set all fields for data to populate on 'submit' command button.  This 'populate' is using a separate sheet command that finds the last row with data in a field and tells my macro population to move down one row.  However, I would like, instead, to insert the row so I can remove extra rows from my document to start with.

Here is my code thus far, including error messages, etc..  Everything is working just as desired for entering in the row below the last with data so I assume I just need to add code to 'InsertEntireRow' someplace but I'm not completely sure where.

Here is my code:

```
`Public Sub cmdSubmit_Click()
`enter code here`'When submit button is clicked

Dim TargetRow As Integer

TargetRow = Sheets("Codes").Range("D37").value + 1
Lodging = format(Lodging, "$#,##0.00")
txtTravelDate = format(txtTravelDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")
txtDepartTime = format(txtDepartTime, "hh:mm am/pm")
txtArrivalTime = format(txtArrivalTime, "hh:mm am/pm")

Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow).EntireRow.Copy
Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow + 1).EntireRow.Insert
Application.CutCopyMode = False



'Error messages presented when submit is selected
If txtTravelDate.value = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must enter Date of Travel", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
If txtDepartTime.value = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must enter Actual Departure Time.  If this was overnight travel, and you traveled the previous day to your destination, enter 12:01 AM", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
If txtArrivalTime.value = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must enter Actual Arrival Time.  If this is an overnight trip and you will not return home today, please enter 12:00 PM", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
If cmbOVNRTN.value = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must select if these expense reimbursements are for Overnight travel or same day Return", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
If Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("f5").value = 1 And txtProjectNumber.value = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must provide a valid Project Number", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
If cmbInOutState.value = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must select if this travel was 'In-State' or 'Out-of-State'", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
If txtTrvlDetails.value = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must provide Travel Details/Description and Business Purpose for this trip", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

'''BEGIN DATA MOVE INTO DATABASE'''
Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 0).value = txtTravelDate 'travel date
Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 1).value = txtDepartTime 'departure time
Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 3).value = txtArrivalTime 'arrival time
Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 5).value = cmbOVNRTN 'overnight or return
Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 12).value = txtProjectNumber 'project number
Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 11).value = cmbInOutState 'in-state or out-of-state
Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 10).value = cmbTravelMode 'travel mode
Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 14).value = txtMilesTraveled 'mileage
Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 13).value = cmbMileageRates 'mileage rate
Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 16).value = Lodging 'no-receipt lodging
Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 17).value = chkMorning 'morning meal
Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 18).value = chkMidday 'midday meal
Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 19).value = chkEvening 'evening meal
Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 6).value = txtTrvlDetails 'travel details/business purpose
'''END DATA MOVE INTO DATABASE'''

  MsgBox "Travel entry for " & txtTravelDate & " is complete.  Select the 'Add' button to add another day of travel.", 0, "Complete"

Unload frmUserTravel
End Sub`
```

Comment: You are writing data entered in textboxes one by one to a defined target row (referring to value in `D37`, apparently calculating the last row, plus +1). - I don't understand where else and where exactly you want to *"insert"* these values (of course you can insert values via an array to avoid one by one population). Where are the mentioned extra lines?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get back to you sooner...  I've been working crazy hours and traveling for the holidays.  What I want it to do, is insert the row as we go.  I want to start with one row only, and with each data entry, I would like it to add a new row and insert into the correct fields.  So I would have a growing document to approximately 48 rows.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Do you mean you want to write any new data line into the first row to get the latest input on top and to move earlier ones down?

Comment: No, I want to insert a row under the first line to write the new data to.  I have a second section below that I want to add the rows above.  Currently I have a section that is about 33 rows but I want to delete those and only add what is needed as data is entered.

Comment: I should have specified that I want to insert a row under the lowest line with data to write the new data to.

Comment: See help example [Range.Insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.range.insert#example); don't forget to fully qualify your range references, instead of the interface sheet name you might use the sheet's CodeName as shown in VBE Tools Window ~> (Name) property in brackets: e.g. `Sheet1.Rows("2:2").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow` :-) @Kristen-Becker

Comment: I updated my code above.  This worked for what I was needing in case anyone else needs this.  :)  I hope it helps someone else!!